# TweetSharp - get by date range

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm using TweetSharp to query Twitter in a C# MVC application.

I want to query a users Twitter feed by date range. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Currently I am querying like this...

```
           var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
            service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);

            ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions u = new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions()
            {
                ScreenName = userName,
                Count = 1000,
                ExcludeReplies = true,
                IncludeRts = false,
                TrimUser = false,
                ContributorDetails = false
            };

            return service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(u);
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TweetSharp does not provide a way to filter tweets by date.  The best you can do is use the SinceId option, which give you all of the tweets after a particular tweet.

You'll need to filter the results yourself.